# Dask function that sleeps without occupying a worker?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

In certain classes of data pipelines it is useful to wait for some external process to finish by (say) watching if a file is written.
Implementing this naively in dask causes a long running task that blocks a worker for its entire duration.

```
def wait_for_file(filename='some_filename', max_wait_time=600):
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - start_time > max_wait_time:
            raise Exception('Timeout')
        if exists(filename):
            return filename
        time.sleep(0.1)

file_exists = delayed(wait_for_file)()    
res = delayed(process_file)(file_exists)
```

How do i make this code not block a worker

Answer (score 2):

Using `secede` and `rejoin` as mentioned in http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html#submit-tasks-from-tasks you can write this waiting function as follows

```
def wait_for_file(filename='some_filename', max_wait_time=600):
    start_time = time.time()
    # detach from the scheduler
    distributed.secede()
    try:
        while True:
            if time.time() - start_time > max_wait_time:
                raise Exception('Timeout')
            if exists(filename):
                # rejoin to the pool of dask executor threads and return
                distributed.rejoin()
                return filename
            time.sleep(0.1)
    finally:
        # in the case where something goes wrong you want to rejoin
        # so that your client knows that this function call failed
        distributed.rejoin()
```